# Returning only date part of datetime string in editorfor template

Tags: datetime, datetime-format, editorformodel

I have the following code to try and return my datetime value from my Editorfor template in the dd/MM/yyyy format without the time value:

```
@Html.EditorFor(c => c.SelectedContent.ExpiryDate, "{0:dd/MM/yyyy }")
```

This however is returning also the time value but it is not what I need, how can I return this so it is only the date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the following line above where you declare `ExpiryDate` in your model

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd/MM/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
```

Comment: Nice one Paddy thanks a lot buddy this was doing me head in :) Will accept in 7 minutes :)

Comment: No problem, had the same problem myself a while back

Comment: Did this interfere with your ModelState being valid? Since changing the date I am unable to save the edited content

Comment: It might do yeah. It is probably due to your database not matching your model. If you do not need the data you can delete the database context and .mdf file, clean and rebuild your project. This will create the database to match your changes. You should read the section called 'Adding Validation Rules to the Model' on the following page, it will show you another way of fixing it.
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-validation-to-the-model

Comment: my database is in the US format but my users are in the UK and so I want dates to display in UK format, db was set by azure to us format